# Calling catalog.set_execution_parameter_value from c# with a boolean parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

When I call the SSISDB catalog.set_execution_parameter_value stored proc to set parameters for the execution of my project, It blows up on a boolean parameter with

> The data type of the input value is not compatible with the data type
>   of the 'Boolean'

I tried using string and object with "False" or "1" value. Is there a way to pass a boolean to this proc from c#?

[image]

SOLUTION:

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("catalog.set_execution_parameter_value", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@execution_id", this.ExecutionID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@object_type", ParamReference);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter_name", ParamName);
        SqlParameter p = cmd.Parameters.Add("@parameter_value", SqlDbType.Variant);
        switch (ParamType) 
        {
            case "String" :
                p.Value = ParamValue;
                break;
            case "Int32" :
                p.Value = Int32.Parse(ParamValue);
                break;
            case "Int64" :
                p.Value = Int64.Parse(ParamValue);
                break;
            case "Boolean" :
                p.Value = bool.Parse(ParamValue);
                break;
        }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What type is ParamValue?  I would expect 0 or 1 to work with SQL because that is what t-sql would look like.  Maybe change this to int?

Comment: The stored proc expects a sql_variant. In c#, I tried setting ParamValue to string and object. It can't be int as some parameters are string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a pure TSQL perspective, the mechanism for setting a package parameter would look like

```
DECLARE @var0 bit = 0;
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value]
    @execution_id
,   @object_type = 30
,   @parameter_name = N'GoFast'
,   @parameter_value = @var0;
```

AddWithValue can be tricky as it attempts to infer the correct data type and sometimes it doesn't go so well.  There's an [informative chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx) with Specifying Parameter Data Types on MSDN. If you rework your C# to explicitly set the data type and then assign a value, does that resolve the issue?

```
OleDbParameter parameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@parameter_value", OleDbType.Variant);
parameter.Value = ParamValue;
```

Comment: Thanks! I had my blinders on with AddWithValue. It still does not recognize a boolean though, the underlying value is a string. I think what I need to do is store type with the parameters and cast the value when setting the variant.

Comment: In addition to usiong Add instead of AddWithValue, I had to specify a parameter type and cast when setting the Variant.

Comment: Perfect. I was just trying to replicate your code and realized you were using the [SQLClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient(v=vs.110).aspx) whereas I was going with OLE in the above